# How to dispaly values of two or more checkbox

Tags: java, jsp

I have this little form:

```
<form action="forma2.jsp" method="POST" target="_blank" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="fit" /> FIT</br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fdu" /> FDU </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fam"/>FAM
    
        
        <input type="text" name="ime"/><br>           
        <input type="submit" value="Potvrdi" />
    </form>
```

And this little code to show me information about selected checkboxes:

```
<body>

    <% if (request.getParameter("fit") != null) { %>
    <p> Today is FIT</p><br>
    <% } else if (request.getParameter("fdu") != null) { %>
    <p> Today is not FDU</p><br>
    <% } else if (request.getParameter("fam") != null) { %>
      <p> Today is not FAM</p><br>
        <% } else { %>
        <p>Please choose one!</p>
    <% }%>
</body>
```

My problem is that I dont know how to make it so I can click on two checkboxes to get information not just only one. So if I selected checkbox number1 and checkbox number2 how to make so program display me information about both checkboxes.

Comment: Hello Tea! What error message are you getting? Or if you are not getting an error message, what is the expected result, and how does that differ from the result that you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You can give same name to all checkboxes you have under your `form` tag and then use `request.getParameterValues("chcks[]")` to get values of all checkboxes . i.e:

Your **jsp** code :

```
 <form action="forma2.jsp" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chcks[]" value="FIT"/>FIT
    <input type="checkbox" name="chcks[]" value="FDU"/>FDU
    <input type="checkbox" name="chcks[]" value="FAM"/>FAM
    <input type="text" name="ime"/><br>           
    <input type="submit" value="Potvrdi" />
  </form>
```

Then to get values from **checkboxes** do like below :

```
  if(request.getParameterValues("chcks[]")!=null){
        //get values of checkbox
        String[] datas = request.getParameterValues("chcks[]");
      //loop through values
        for(int i=0;i< datas.length;i++){
        //print
        out.println("Today is "+datas[i]);
        
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it set up as if/else if/else if. This will only choose 1 to display. You can fix this by changing each to an individual if statement.